# Material ui resposive date picker

Tags: material-ui

Currently I am working on material ui component library. I read the documentation and I saw there date picker responsive method.([see here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness)).It mentioned we can responsive the date picker using desktopModeMediaQuery prop.I search every where in the documentation and didn't see how to use this prop and I didn't see any example as well. I looking for your great support. And I would like know that are there other ways of responsive the date picker in material ui. In here I used responsive word And It means when we change the width of the calendar picker, It should be responsive with the window screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the documentation [ClickHere](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/#heading-props), I didnt workout,

By default, the DatePicker component renders the desktop version if the media query @media (pointer: fine) matches. This can be customized with the desktopModeMediaQuery prop.

> desktopModeMediaQuery="@media (pointer: fine)"

Comment: I inspect the material ui picker in chrome dev tool and I override the styles it has.iT has max and min property to resposive the picker. But when I reduce it max width and min width It kind of wierd. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Don't do that, you can follow what ever the given documentation.

Comment: ,Yes I do it according to the documentation(using styled hook in the materila ui v5).Have tried before that  how to change height and width of the date picker and when you changing the height or width, that picker should be looks nice?

Comment: @R.G.Krish  Could you please provide detail of usage examples for `desktopModeMediaQuery`?