# DatePicker component from mui display different model based on the screen size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have `DatePicker` component from MUI and this is what it looks like when I open it on the PC screen.

[image]

This is what it looks like when it's a mobile screen.
[image]

It seems like MUI automatically switched the view of `DatePicker` for mobile.

Is there a way to keep the PC view of `DatePicker` for the mobile screen?

This is [code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-lamarr-2s6wv9?file=/demo.js)
Here is [MUI DatePicker component document](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/)

```
import * as React from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

#### Attempts

Currently, I was able to display the PC view of DatePicker on the mobile screen, but that's only I open the google developer tool and toggle the device toolbar.

When I close it, the `DatePicker` will be displayed as the Mobile view on both the PC and mobile screen.

```
import * as React from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        desktopModeMediaQuery="@media (pointer: coarse)"
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: You linked the docs, but you probably should look at this section right here: https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness

As it states `DatePicker` auto swaps, `MobileDatePicker` = mobile view, `DesktopDatePicker` = desktop view.

Comment: @JacobSmit Thanks for the link. Do you know how to use `desktopModeMediaQuery`? This is what the link you gave me says to use, but I couldn't any examples of how to use it. Found a link asking the same question, but this also doesn't include an example of usage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382591/material-ui-resposive-date-picker

Comment: If you just want the desktop picker the whole time, can you not just use `DesktopDatePicker` instead of `DatePicker`?

Comment: The `desktopModeMediaQuery` should just take something like '@media screen' or '@media (min-width: 0px)' to tell it to show desktop the whole time.

Comment: @JacobSmit You are so true. I thought I already checked but it seems like having `DesktopDatePicker`  works both on PC and mobile. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Having `DesktopDatePicker` works both on the PC and mobile.

[mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness)