# How to use desktopModeMediaQuery from MUI DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I like to know to use `desktopModeMediaQuery` from material ui.

The only link I found was this [Material ui resposive date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382591/material-ui-resposive-date-picker).

This also doesn't include how to use `desktopModeMediaQuery`.

Do I have to import it from `mui`? or the document says `This can be customized with the desktopModeMediaQuery prop.` so I can just have this as a prop and I don't have to import it?

How can I use this prop? or is this for stylying?

If you can provide any example of how to use it, I really appreciate it.

I want to display the PC version of `DatePicker` on the mobile screen.

The doc link for [`desktopModeMediaQuery`](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [useMediaQuery] like below:

```
// Import useMediaQuery from MUI
import useMediaQuery from '@mui/material/useMediaQuery';
       
export default function TestMediaQuery() {
  // Setting media query using this hook
  const matches = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');
          
  return <div>
      If your screen width is bigger than 600px, matches: ${matches}
    </div>
}a
```

Try this link for more reference [MUI useMediaQuery](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness)

And you can also implement PC version MUI DatePicker in mobile screen

```
import * as React from 'react';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DesktopDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker';

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(dayjs('2023-02-23T4:11:54'));

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <Stack spacing={3}>
        <DesktopDatePicker
          label="Date desktop"
          inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </Stack>
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Try this link for more reference [MUI Datepicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/#react-components)

I hope this answer is helpful for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having `DesktopDatePicker` component works both on the PC and mobile.

mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#responsiveness